# why does my iteration count start at 2 instead of one?

Tags: python

I have to write a program showing the total number of payments and total amount paid for a mortgage. The problem assumes an extra $1000 a month for the first 12 months. The answer $929,965.62 over 342 months. The output I get is $929,965.62 over 343 months. The problem is my code starts counting at 2 but the first amount is correct.

```py
principal = 500000.0
rate = 0.05
payment = 2684.11
total_paid = 0.0
extra_payment = 1000
payment_number = 1

while principal > 0 and payment_number <=12:
    principal = principal * (1+rate/12) - (payment + extra_payment)
    total_paid = total_paid + (payment + extra_payment)
    payment_number += 1
    print(payment_number, round(total_paid, 2))

else:
    while principal > 0:
        principal = principal * (1+rate/12) - payment
        total_paid = total_paid + payment
        payment_number += 1
        print(payment_number, round(total_paid, 2))
```

I don't understand why the above code starts at 2 and the code below starts counting at 1.

```
height = 100
bounce = 1
while bounce <= 10:
    height = height * (3/5)
    print(bounce, round(height, 4))
    bounce += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First example you `print` **after** you increment `payment_number`; second sample it's reversed. Change

```
payment_number += 1
print(payment_number, round(total_paid, 2))
```

to

```
print(payment_number, round(total_paid, 2))
payment_number += 1
```